# What is the Lock Screen?

Tags: lock-screens, motorola-moto-g

I don't understand the concept of "Lock Screen", can someone explain it?  Is it the main screen?  I have a Moto G 2nd gen.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts!
While the community here is based around answering questions, we expected that the person does some research on the topic before asking a certain question. For example, when you put the name of your question as a Google search query, the first result directs you to the Wikipedia article which answers your question perfectly.

Comment: A little search on our site helps as well. Hint: our [tags](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags) are sometimes a great resource, as they have "tag wikis" explaining their means. In your case, the [lock-screens tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lock-screens/info) answers your question, which is why I've added that tag to your post.

Answer (score 1):

The [lock screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_screen) is the screen that shows up when you first turn on the phone, or wake the phone up.  It is the first layer of defense for your phone.  You have many options:

- No lock screen(least amount of defense.
- Swipe motion(which means you just have to swipe it to open it up)
- Face recognition(which when you want to unlock your phone, you will have to face it and it will recognize your face with the camera)
- Pattern lock(which is just as it sounds, gives you 9 dots and you have to make a 4+ pattern to unlock the phone)
- Number lock(where you pick a 4 digit code that you must input before you can unlock the phone.)